# angularjs - what does a :: mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In some angular js files, I see below syntax. What does a double colan "::" mean?

```
<span>{{::x}}</span>
<div>{{::y.z()}}</div>
```

Comment: This is for one-way binding, an angular 1.3+ feature

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called *one-way databinding*, and appeared since **Angular 1.3**. For older versions, there is an equivalent add-on solution called **[bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)**.

From [Angular JS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) :

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value

Basically, when you write :

```
{{::x}}
```

angular will destroy the watcher when `x` will be defined. The counterpart of it is that `x` won't be updated anymore  in the view if his value changes after that destroy.

Comment: And this means that if you're certain a value is not going to change (or it might, but you do not want it to), you should always use `::` because it makes the page use significantly less resources. One or two watches is not going to make a difference, but turning 300 into 200 will make a very big difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature edited in angular js 1.3+

## {{ ::title }}

only bind value first time which happens after the first digest if the expression result.
[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is used for one time binding. It provides the ability to render data once and let it persist without being affected by future Model updates. See more details in the link below:

https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135